# Having trouble coding a mini-game (Guess Who?)

Tags: python, xcode

I'm making a code of guessing the name game, but the function doesn't work.

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1IgT.png)

```
import random
#Almacena en una variable los nombres
actores = ["Leonardo","Pedro","Marilyn","Tom","Brad","Angelina","Meryl"]
nombreelegido=print("Adivina quien es el actor que estoy pensando de los siguientes nombres:",actores)
nobreelegido=str(input("Dame el nombre del actor:" ,))
#random.choice elige nombre aleatorio
nombrerandom=random.choice(actores)
print("El nombre del actor era:",nombrerandom)

def validanombre(nombreelegido,nombrerandom):
    if nombreelegido==nombrerandom :
        print("Su respuesta es correcta")
    else:
        print("Su respuesta es incorrecta")
    validanombre(nombreelegido,nombrerandom)
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your code. See [this long explanation of why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3890632).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function inside the function itself. Try replacing the last 6 lines of your code with this:

```
def validanombre(nombreelegido, nombrerandom):
    if nombreelegido==nombrerandom:
            print("Correct!")
    else:
            print("Incorrect!")

validanombre(nombreelegido, nombrerandom)
```

**Note:** Next time, please type your code instead of taking a screenshot it is easier to fix bugs as copy-pasting is an option. Also specify what you mean by the function not working, and provide the error in the question. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) link before asking questions next time.